# Grep for a string with * in it

Tags: unix, grep

I am trying to find a string in a set of files using Grep command.
String is "ST*820", now this string itself has a * in it so I believe conventional methods of using grep will not work.

Can someone please suggest me something that can help me out with this.

Thanks
Raghav

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `*`,

```
grep \\* <FILES>
```

or (using pipe),

```
$ echo "ST*820" | grep \\*
ST*820
```

Comment: or `echo "ST*820" | grep -E '\*'`

Comment: Thanks Avinash but I still do not get it. My idea was to use grep "ST*820" <<file name>> but it is not working . Here is the sample data from the file. GS*RA*014578892*IGIHCJEEJ*20140827*1200*5893*X*004010
ST*820*000005933
As you can see from this, I need to search for ST*820 from it